# Form post returning blank array

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to make a form for a user signup page however when I submit the form I keep getting a blank array. When I switched `method="post"` to `method="get"` the array was filled with the appropriate values. I have no idea what is going on!

index.html

```
<form action="config.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <div class="select">
        <select name="status">
            <option selected="selected" disabled='disabled'>Status</option>
            <option value="student">Student</option>
                                <option value="faculty">Faculty</option>
            <option value="alumni">Alumni</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" class="btn large color wow center fadeInLeft">
    </div>
</form>
```

config.php

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Result

> Array ( )

Comment: Works for me, tried and tested it. Might be a configuration issue?

Comment: Yeah there's no reason this wouldn't work. Check your browser inspector, make sure it's actually posting. Check your PHP for typos -- make sure you're not still printing out `$_GET`.

Comment: Do you think it might be from my local host? I'm using aws for the backend.